# Can you create a javascript method that creates an openlayers map object?

Tags: javascript, automation, openlayers

I am trying to automate the creation of openlayers map objects, as follows
HTML:

```
<div id="map1"></div>
<div id="map2"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function createMap(mapObject, mapDiv) {
mapObject = new ol.Map({
   layers: new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()}),
   target: mapDiv,
   view: new ol.View({center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([32.0, 34.5]), zoom: 8})
})
}
createMap(map1, "map1");
createMap(map2, "map2");
```

Say I wanted to create some event that overlays a layer on either of the map objects when that events occurs, I could modify the above code as follows:
HTML

```
...
<button id="btn1" type='submit'>Load To Map 1</button>
<button id="btn2" type='submit'>Load To Map 2</button>
```

JavaScript

```
...
$('#btn1').on('click', function(e) {
const key = 'some random numbers';
let raster = new TileLayer({
      minZoom: 14, // visible at zoom levels above 14
      source: new TileJSON({
        url: 'https://api.maptiler.com/maps/outdoor/tiles.json?key=' + key,
        tileSize: 512,
      }),
    });
createMap(map1, "map1");
map1.addLayer(raster);
}
$('#btn2').on('click', function(e) {
const key = "some random numbers";
let raster = new TileLayer({
      source: new XYZ({
        attributions: attributions,
        url:
          'https://api.maptiler.com/tiles/satellite/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg?key=' + key,
        maxZoom: 20,
      })
    });
createMap(map2, "map2");
map1.addLayer(raster);
}
```

The question is, why doesn't this work with an error that map1 or map2 is undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define a variable through a function.

What you can do, is return the object in the function instead.

```js
function createMap(mapDiv) {
  return new ol.Map({
    layers: new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()}),
    target: mapDiv,
    view: new ol.View({center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([32.0, 34.5]), zoom: 8})
  })
}
```

Then define a variable by

```js
let map1 = createMap("map1");
```

So, your code will be

```js
$('#btn1').on('click', function(e) {
  const key = 'some random numbers';
  let raster = new TileLayer({
    minZoom: 14, // visible at zoom levels above 14
    source: new TileJSON({
      url: 'https://api.maptiler.com/maps/outdoor/tiles.json?key=' + key,
      tileSize: 512,
    }),
  });
  let map1 = createMap("map1");
  map1.addLayer(raster);
}

$('#btn2').on('click', function(e) {
  const key = "some random numbers";
  let raster = new TileLayer({
    source: new XYZ({
      attributions: attributions,
      url: 'https://api.maptiler.com/tiles/satellite/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg?key=' + key,
      maxZoom: 20,
    })
  });

  let map2 = createMap("map2")
  map2.addLayer(raster);
}
```